# Jquery animate div to increase height on click and collapse on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a div that when clicked increases its height, then when you click the close button, it goes back to its original height.

I've managed to make a jquery script that increases height on click, and decreases on second click, but it screws up the layout for some reason as shown: [image: ..]

It starts like this and should end like this on second click: 
[image]

Here is the html:

```
<div class="work">
    <h1 class="heading">Selected Projects</h1>
    <div class="line"></div>
        <ul>
            <li id="darl">
                <div class="container2"><div class="block">
                    <img class="bg-image"  id="bgimg1" src="Images/perspective2final2pfolio2.jpg">
                </div></div>
                <p>1. Darlington Terrace<i id="close1" class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i></p>
            </li>

            <li><div class="thinline"></div></li>
            <li id="chil">
                <div class="container2"><div class="block">
                    <img class="bg-image"  id="bgimg2" src="Images/DSC_0756.jpg">
                </div></div>
                <p>2. Children's Playground</p>
            </li>

            <li><div class="thinline"></div></li>
            <li id="lawn">
                <div class="container2"><div class="block">
                    <img class="bg-image"  id="bgimg3"src="Images/perspective2final2pfolio2.jpg">
                </div></div>
                <p>3. Lawn Bowl Bakery Bridge</p>
            </li>

            <li><div class="thinline"></div></li>
            <li id="aque">
                <div class="container2"><div class="block">
                    <img class="bg-image"  id="bgimg4"src="Images/perspective2final2pfolio2.jpg">
                </div></div>
                <p>4. Aqueduct: Museum of Architecture</p>
            </li>

            <li><div class="thinline"></div></li>
            <li id="velo">
                <div class="container2"><div class="block">
                    <img class="bg-image"  id="bgimg5"src="Images/perspective2final2pfolio2.jpg">
                </div></div>
                <p>5. Velocity Frequent Flyer Website</p>
            </li>

            <li><div class="thinline"></div></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
```

Here is the jquery (ignore mouseenter part and overflow, for another function in the script, and the printF() was to print the height into the console):

```
$("#darl").on("click", function(){
    if($("#darl").height() == 38){

        $(this).finish().animate({
            height: "300px",
        }, 500);
        $("#darl .block").css("overflow", "visible");
        $(this).off('mouseenter');
    }else{
        $(this).finish().animate({
           height: "38px",
        }, 500);  
    }
printF();
        });
```

Here are the full code files on github:
https://github.com/mingweichan/CVwebsite

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is problem you are facing and what will be the outcome you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking for a hard-coded height is not a best idea.
It is much more convenient to utilize CSS.

Just declare a class for "expandable" items, and a class for its state. Then, use jQuery to toggle these classes. CSS transitions will help you implement animation.

```js
$("#darl").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
});
```

```css
#darl {
  height: 38px;
  background-color: grey;
  
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  
  overflow: hidden;
}

#darl.expanded {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li id="darl">
  <div class="container2">
    <div class="block">
      <img class="bg-image" id="bgimg1" src="Images/perspective2final2pfolio2.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>1. Darlington Terrace<i id="close1" class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i>
  </p>
</li>
```

Now, you are also able to change `overflow`using CSS rule:

```
#darl .block {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#darl.expanded .block {
  overflow: visible;
}
```